# if all argument value error for pay all command economy bot

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

**My code works but when I include the pay 'all' command it seems to give me an error.**
I want the bot to basically when I tell it to ".pay @example#0001 all" its selects all 'bal'

**MY CODE:**

```py
@client.command(aliases=['send'])
async def pay(ctx, member : discord.Member, amount = None):
    await open_account(ctx.author)
    await open_account(member)
    
    if amount == None:
        await ctx.send('Please enter the amount')
        return

    bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
   


    amount = int(amount)
    if amount == 'all':     #This
        amount = bal[0]     #Wont work

    if amount>bal[1]:
        await ctx.send('You do not have that much money!')
        return
    if amount<0:
        await ctx.send('Amount must be positive!')
        return

    await update_bank(ctx.author,amount, 'wallet')
    await update_bank(member,-1*amount,'bank') 

    await ctx.send(f'{ctx.author.mention} Payed {amount} coins! How generous!')
```

**THE ERROR:**

```py
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'all'
```

Comment: You cannot check for a string after trying to convert to int, because if it was not a valid number then it is already too late. In any case you will need to guard against the exception, in case the user types some other kind of garbage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Change this:**

```py
if amount == None:
    await ctx.send('Please enter the amount')
    return

bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
   


amount = int(amount)
if amount == 'all':     #This
    amount = bal[0]     #Wont work
```

**TO:**

```py
bal = await update_bank(ctx.author)
if amount == 'all':
    amount = bal[0]
else:
    try:
        amount = int(amount)
    except ValueError:
        await ctx.send(f'Invalid amount({amount}) Must be "all" or an integer')
        return

amount = int(amount) #This has to be after we define "amount == 'all'"
 #THE REST OF THE CODE
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
    amount = int(amount)
    if amount == 'all':     #This
        amount = bal[0]     #Wont work
```

To this:

```
    if amount == 'all':     #This
        amount = bal[0]     #Wont work
    else:
        try:
            amount = int(amount)
        except ValueError:
            await ctx.send(f'Invalid amount({amount}) Must be "all" or an integer')
            return
```

The idea here is that you want to check to see if "all" is sent, and if not, try to cast it to an integer. If you cannot cast to int() you will get a ValueError as you noted. Catch the ValueError and then reply with a message to the user.